# mSampleRate is different between iPad mini and iPad Air

Tags: ios7, core-audio

I'm trying to capture mic audio with code bottom.

```
NSLog(@"sampleBuffer = %@",sampleBuffer);
```

will return

```
sampleBuffer = CMSampleBuffer 0x155d111a0 retainCount: 1 allocator: 0x191e590c0
invalid = NO
dataReady = YES
makeDataReadyCallback = 0x0
makeDataReadyRefcon = 0x0
formatDescription = <CMAudioFormatDescription 0x170119e90 [0x191e590c0]> {
mediaType:'soun' 
mediaSubType:'lpcm' 
mediaSpecific: {
    ASBD: {
        mSampleRate: 44100.000000 
        mFormatID: 'lpcm' 
        mFormatFlags: 0xc 
        mBytesPerPacket: 2 
        mFramesPerPacket: 1 
        mBytesPerFrame: 2 
        mChannelsPerFrame: 1 
        mBitsPerChannel: 16     } 
    cookie: {(null)} 
    ACL: {(null)} 
} 
extensions: {(null)}
}
sbufToTrackReadiness = 0x0
numSamples = 1024
sampleTimingArray[1] = {
    {PTS = {810106869118125/1000000000 = 810106.869}, DTS = {INVALID}, duration = {1/44100 = 0.000}},
}
sampleSizeArray[1] = {
    sampleSize = 2,
}
dataBuffer = 0x178118f60
```

"mSampleRate: **44100.000000**" on iPad Air, even though "mSampleRate: **11025.000000**" on iPad mini (non retina). Both of them iOS7.

I don't know why. What I want is "mSampleRate: **11025.000000**" even on iPad Air.

How shoud I do?

After this, I'm tring to encode the stream to aac. it's working on 11025 iPad mini and on 44100 iPad mini and Air.

**CODE**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell <AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate>

@property AVCaptureAudioDataOutput *audioDataOutput;
@property AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property AVAudioSession *audioSession;

@end

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    [self.audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
    self.audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    double hwSampleRate = 11025.0;
    [self.audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:hwSampleRate error:nil];
    [self.audioSession setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels:1 error:nil];
    [self.audioSession setPreferredOutputNumberOfChannels:1 error:nil];
    [self.audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice;
    captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioInput;
    audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];
    if (!audioInput) {
        NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
        return;
    }

    self.captureSession = nil;
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    self.captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = YES;
    [self.captureSession addInput:audioInput];

    self.audioDataOutput = nil;
    self.audioDataOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
    [self.captureSession addOutput:self.audioDataOutput];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("AudioDataOutputQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self.audioDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self setSelected:NO];
    [self.captureSession stopRunning];

}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"sampleBuffer = %@",sampleBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Try providing a pointer to an error object and see if calling `setPreferredSampleRate:error:` fails. Use the error object returned to see why it failed.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.

    NSError *e = nil;
    [self.audioSession setPreferredSampleRate:hwSampleRate error:&e];
    NSLog(@"error =%@", e);

says

    error =(null)

on iPad Air and mini.

Comment: Yes, but does the method return success or not? Also, could be a but in Apple's implementation.

Comment: return no error. iPad air returns 44100 pcm data even though "setPreferredSampleRate:11025" and iPad mini (not retina) returns 11025 pcm data.(this is what i want) so making 44100 aac encoding program works fine for both. but just mini works fine for 11025 case. difference between air and mini is 64 or 32bit cpu, and 3 build-in mic or one. I'm exploring these stuff now.

Comment: error found at setPreferredInputNumberOfChannels:1 and setPreferredOutputNumberOfChannels:1.  if i delete 2 of them even iPad mini start receiving 44100 pcm data.

Comment: That's great! Please add an answer and mark as answered.